# Why does a wildcard on a generic parameter require an explicit cast?

Tags: java

I have a function:

```
<T> T get(Class<T> fetchType) {
    ...
}
```

So, if I were to do something like:

```
String x = get(String.class);
```

this is all good.

However, in another function:

```
<R> R otherFunction(R base) {
    return get(base.getClass());
}
```

Gives me an error, because `base.getClass()` returns `? extends R`.

```
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that capture of ? extends Object conforms to R
inference variable T has incompatible bounds:
equality constraints: capture of ? extends Object upper bounds: Object, R
```

Now from what I understand, the function `get(Class<T> x)` returns `T`, so when called with `? extends R`, which let's say is `CAP#1`, but since `get` now returns `CAP#1`, assigning it to type `R` should not be a problem. To test this, I tried:

```
Class<? extends CharSequence> stringClass = String.class;
CharSequence x = get(stringClass);
```

This seems to work without any issues. What's going wrong?

EDIT: Is this because of type-erasure, that at runtime no information about `R` is available, but `CharSequence` is? Which still doesn't make sense because isn't this purely checked during the compile phase alone?

So, it turns out that`Object.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends |X|>` and not `Class<? extends X>`, where `|X|` is the erasure of `X` which is why it works for concrete types (like `? extends CharSequence`, but not for a generic type). IntelliJ probably does not report it accurately, which caused the confusion: [image: http://i.imgur.com/yE8LswM.jpg] (I tried taking a screenshot, but the pop-up kept on going away).

Comment: Please show us the context in which you get that error. Is it in the compilation of `otherFunction` or in an attempt to invoke it? If the latter, please add the code that invokes it.

Comment: Your error says `getClass()` returns `? extends Object`, the compiler cannot resolve it to `? extends R`.

Comment: Also, which version of Java? Java 8 has better type inference than Java 7.

Comment: The method `java.lang.Object.getClass()` returns `Class<?>` and not `Class<? extends R>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree that it should be. I have voted to close this as a dupe for the link you posted. And thank you so much for taking the time :)

Comment: @RealSkeptic jdk 8u112

Comment: For those interested: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-163989

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is described in the Javadoc of [`Object.getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()):

> ```
> public final Class<?> getClass()
> ```
>
> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which `getClass` is called.

So, when you call `base.getClass()`, the actual result is `Class<?>`, since the erasure of `R` is `Object`. It's not `Class<? extends R>`.

Comment: This is what had me confused in that case: http://i.imgur.com/yE8LswM.jpg

Comment: @RohanPrabhu I'd say that's a bug in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter `R base` will allow all objects of your desired generic class < R >, but also all objects, which are subclasses of < R > can be put into this method. Because of this, you don't know what will happen if you call base.getClass(), you expect < R > but it could also be a class wich extends generic R.

Comment: But the example of the `String` (which is a subclass of `CharSequence`) works.

Comment: Yes, because you said it extended charsequence. All possible subclasses you can make of String, still are also classes which extend charsequence.

Comment: Which is fine, it of course could be any class which extends `R`, but that class would still be `assignable` to R, which seems to work perfectly fine when I do `? extends CharSequence`. It accepts, `String`, but any instance of `String` is still assignable to `CharSequence`.