# Difference between Mockito.<Response>any().getClass() and Mockito.<Class<Response>>any()?

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I am trying to understanding how the generics work in case of Mockito.

I am trying to mock the `RestTemplate`, however the following code does not compile and I don't know why:

```
var expectedResponse = createServiceResponse();

when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class),
        Mockito.<HttpEntity<Object>>any(),
        Mockito.<ServiceResponse>any().getClass(), anyMap()))
        .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(expectedResponse));
```

The compiler keeps giving me the error message:

```
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<T>)
```

But when I switch `Mockito.<ServiceResponse>any().getClass()` with `Mockito.<Class<ServiceResponse>>any()` the compilation succeeds.

Why is this happening ?

**What is the difference between `Mockito.<ServiceResponse>any().getClass()` and `Mockito.<Class<ServiceResponse>>any()` ?**

They should be the same thing right ?

**I mean the class of `ServiceResponse` should be `Class<ServiceResponse>`. Right ?**

I don't have a good grasp of advanced generics so I can't understand what the compiler is doing.

Please do add some description in the answer so that I can understand why this is working the way it is suppose to.

Answer (score 1):

#### What is the difference between `Mockito.<ServiceResponse>any().getClass()` and `Mockito.<Class<ServiceResponse>>any()?`

`Mockito.<ServiceResponse>any()` is an instance of `ServiceResponse`. And calling [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()) from any instance return `Class<?>`. `getClass()` is created  to get the actual class of the instance, usually for **runtime** comparison.

On the other hand,
`Mockito.<Class<ServiceResponse>>any()` is an instance of `Class<ServiceResponse>`

#### I mean the class of ServiceResponse should be Class. Right ?

Not really, consider following code

```
    private void dummy(ServiceResponse response) {
        System.out.println(response.getClass().equals(ServiceResponse.class));
    }
```

You can't guarantee the output is always true, as `response` can be of type `CustomServiceResponse`(extending ServiceResponse)

Further reading:
[What is the difference between a.getClass() and A.class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947768/what-is-the-difference-between-a-getclass-and-a-class-in-java)
[Why does a wildcard on a generic parameter require an explicit cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605303/why-does-a-wildcard-on-a-generic-parameter-require-an-explicit-cast)
[Java: getClass() of bounded type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144556/java-getclass-of-bounded-type)

Answer (score 0):

Only in these cases, where the compiler cannot garantuee the returned type of the method (here `restTemplate.exchange`) we can use the non-type-safe equivalent syntax:

```
Mockito.doReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(expectedResponse))
    .when(restTemplate)
    .exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class),
        Mockito.<HttpEntity<Object>>any(),
        Mockito.<ServiceResponse>any().getClass(), anyMap()));
```